# A fair coin is flipped until the first tail appears, in general we win \$ $2^k $. St. Petersburg problem.

Tags: probability, random-variables

For the St.Peterburg problem (Example 3.5.5), find the expected payoff if

(a) the amounts won are $c^k$ instead of $2^k$, where $0 < c < 2$.

(b) the amounts won are $\log(2^k)$.

The original problem says: Consider the following game. A fair coin is flipped until the first tail appears; we win two dollars if it appears on the first toss, four dollars if it appears on the second toss and in general \$$2^k$ if it first occurs on the kth toss. Let the random variable X denote our winnings. How much should we have to pay in order for this to be a fair game?

Then note: $p_X(2^k) = \Pr(X = 2^k) = \frac1{2^k}$ , for $k = 1,2,\ldots$

Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[X] =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty(2^k) \cdot p_X(2^k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(2^k)\cdot 1/2^k = 1 + 1+ 1 + 1+\ldots$

which is a divergent sum.

Then, trying to use the information from original problem. Instead of $2^k$ use $c^k..

Then $\mathbb{E}[X] =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty(c^k) \cdot p_X(c^k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(c^k)\cdot c/2^k = 1 + 1+ 1 + 1+\ldots$

. Can someone please help me? I don't really understand because I getting the wrong answer.

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: $(c^k)\cdot c/2^k$ certainly isn't 1...

Comment: where does that c/2^k come from? Then would it not be E(X) = Σ_(sum of all k) (c^k) * p__X(1/2^k) = Σ_(k = 1 to ∞) (c^k)*1/2^k ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{align}\mathsf E[c^X] &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c^k p_X(k)\\[2ex] p_{X}(k)&=1/2^k \\[2ex] \therefore \mathsf E[c^X] &=\sum_{k-1}^\infty c^k/2^k\\&= \frac{c}{(2-c)} & \text{geometric series converges when: }|c/2|<1\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

Now win win $c^k$ dollars **BUT** the probabilities do not change. They are still $2^k$.